# ActiveMQ Artemis: Obtain list of acceptors via JMX

Tags: jmx, activemq-artemis

How can I retrieve the list of configured acceptors in ActiveMQ Artemis via Jolokia/JMX (and curl)? I need to reload the acceptors after a TLS certificate update but looks like passing the acceptor name is mandatory. Unfortunately, I cannot just pass a static name because we use different acceptors, all using TLS – and don’t want to change the reloading code just because the acceptor config changed.

```sh
curl -s -f -u username:password -H 'Origin: localhost' 'http://127.0.0.1:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="borker-primary-0"'
```

shows the connectors, but not the acceptors.

This question is related to a change introduced in v2.18.0, see [question on TLS certificate reload](https://serverfault.com/questions/1023332/activemq-artemis-tls-certificate-reload/1023338).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `getConnectors` method on the main `ActiveMQServerControl` MBean which is why Jolokia's `read` command returns those values. However, there is no corresponding `getAcceptors` method, but you can use Jolokia's `list` command to effectively get the same information. Use something like this:

```
curl -s -f -u username:password -H 'Origin: localhost' 'http://127.0.0.1:8161/console/jolokia/list/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="borker-primary-0"'
```

Then look through the results for `component=acceptors` and you'll be able to find all the acceptors with their respective names.

This is a bit of a hack but a necessary one at this point given the lack of a management method to get the acceptors. I've opened [ARTEMIS-3601](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3601) and sent a PR to deal with this use-case so in future versions this won't be necessary. You'll just be able to invoke `getAcceptors` or inspect them from the output of Jolokia's `read` command.

Comment: Thank you, Justin. The solution feels a bit like a hack but works.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Indeed, yes. Thanks for your PR, much appreciated. Looking forward to the next release containing `getAcceptors`.